# Global variable is not changing on button press (scope issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have a declared variable and jQuery code telling a button to store a form's value as the value of that variable and execute a function.

```
var verb = "";
$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
   verb = $('#enter').val();
   teConjugate();
});
```

In the teConjugate() function, I have placed a lot of functions and variables using the "verb" variable that I want to use outside the teConjugate() function. However, when I declare these functions and variables globally, they use the globally declared "verb" (which is an empty string). I've done research and I know that it has something to do with the rendering of the page (as console.log does not raise the same issues).

The only thing I've thought of is putting said functions and variables in to a initialize function which executes on button click, to reduce the hassle of copy pasting everything. However, this did not work either.

Is there any solution? Any help would be appreciated.

[JSbin with the dilemma.](http://jsbin.com/yezij/7/edit)
As one can see, there are a lot of variables and functions that would be more useful outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you have shown here ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4A9f4/)). I suspect it is something to do with your `teConjugate();` function.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ9Q6/) is what I'm trying to accomplish. As you can see, when I alert usefulFunctionDeclaredOutsideOfTeConjugate it doesn't take the new value of verb.

Comment: Are you expecting that if you type "This", the second alert will be "This is cool". If so then that wont work. You have already initialized the variable to `... = verb + "is cool!"` where verb is an empty string.  A variable wont change unless you specifically set it.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Is there anyway I can initialize the variables in a convenient way so that I don't have to retype them in every function I want to use them in?

Comment: You could create a separate function `GetUsefulFunctionDeclaredOutsideOfTeConjugate() that returns the value - [see updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ9Q6/2/)

Comment: Thanks, this works! However, I have to declare a lot of things that could be variables as functions instead. I'll experiment with this method!

Comment: Right now I've simply placed all the code inside the buttonclick function, and plan to make it update the properties outside object so I can store its information.